# expand python regex definition of 'word'

Tags: python, regex

Can python expand what is matched by `w+` and `W+`?  How would I add more characters to its list?

Why?  Going through some text and finding there are some characters I would like to add to the word definition such as `&` and `æ`.

If I cannot add to the word definition, then how do I add to my functions:

```
re.findall(r'\w+', txt)
re.findall(r'\W+', txt)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well `\w` is a predefined set of characters, you can't programatically modify the meaning of `\w`. But you can setup a group that will match any character in `\w` plus any other characters you want using the `[]` syntax. So you'd change your regex to

```
[\w\&æ]+
```

or

```
[\W\&æ]+
```

respectively

This matches any character in the `\w` or `\W` set and adds & and æ. You can play around with these expressions on [regexpal](http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=%5B%5Cw%5C&%C3%A6%5D%2b&input=KittyCat&%C3%A6).

Comment: Is there any way to find out what all the characters `\w` matches?

Comment: @martineau when I google "regex \w" I get lots of useful definitions. Basically it means anything in the ranges "A-Z", "a-z"' "0-9", and the "_" character.

Comment: These examples are very helpful... and if I needed to search for &amp; too?

Comment: `\W` includes `&` and `æ`, so `[\W&æ]` is the same as `[\W]`. First decide on the positive character set (`[\w&æ]`) and then just negate it for the negative character set (`[^\w&æ]`).

Answer (score 0):

Use a character group in a pre-compiled pattern.

```
lower_match_chars = re.compile('[\\w\\&]+')
upper_match_chars = re.compile('[\\W\\&]+')
all_lower_matches = re.findall(lower_match_chars, txt)
all_upper_matches = re.findall(upper_match_chars, txt)
```

Comment: Raw literals are easier to work with when entering regex strings - no need to double up all the backslashes.

Comment: I prefer not using raws as it is so easy to miss that single r and introduce tricky bugs.  But yes, if you like raws, you don't have to use the double backslash.

Comment: I don't think you need to escape `&` inside a character class, either.

Comment: Meh, I was just copying Doug on that one.